# How to use KEYDOWN?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to exit the program when the escape key is pressed. I am having some trouble doing that.

When I take out the door() line it works;

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print("key pressed")
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                print("key pressed")
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    #door()
```

This is the command prompt readout

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents\Fan game>python testing_file.py
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
key pressed
key pressed

C:\Users\Me\Documents\Fan game>
```

But as soon as I add that line back in, it stops working.

My door function;

```
def door():
    
    global var_door
    
    image_door_1 = pygame.image.load(r'textures\door\frame_1.png')
    image_door_2 = pygame.image.load(r'textures\door\frame_2.png')
    image_door_3 = pygame.image.load(r'textures\door\frame_3.png')
    image_door_4 = pygame.image.load(r'textures\door\frame_4.png')
    image_door_5 = pygame.image.load(r'textures\door\frame_5.png')
    image_door_6 = pygame.image.load(r'textures\door\frame_6.png')
    
    image_door_1_size = image_door_1.get_rect().size
    image_door_2_size = image_door_2.get_rect().size
    image_door_3_size = image_door_3.get_rect().size
    image_door_4_size = image_door_4.get_rect().size
    image_door_5_size = image_door_5.get_rect().size
    image_door_6_size = image_door_6.get_rect().size
    
    centered_image_door_1 = [(display_size[0] - image_door_1_size[0])/2, (display_size[1] - image_door_1_size[1])/2]
    centered_image_door_2 = [(display_size[0] - image_door_2_size[0])/2, (display_size[1] - image_door_2_size[1])/2]
    centered_image_door_3 = [(display_size[0] - image_door_3_size[0])/2, (display_size[1] - image_door_3_size[1])/2]
    centered_image_door_4 = [(display_size[0] - image_door_4_size[0])/2, (display_size[1] - image_door_4_size[1])/2]
    centered_image_door_5 = [(display_size[0] - image_door_5_size[0])/2, (display_size[1] - image_door_5_size[1])/2]
    centered_image_door_6 = [(display_size[0] - image_door_6_size[0])/2, (display_size[1] - image_door_6_size[1])/2]
    
    mouse_down = False
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_down = True
    
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if 0 < x < 253 and 0 < y < 226:
        if mouse_down:
            if var_door == 0:
                screen.blit(image_door_1, centered_image_door_1)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.01)
                    
                screen.blit(image_door_2, centered_image_door_2)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.01)

                screen.blit(image_door_3, centered_image_door_3)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.01)

                screen.blit(image_door_4, centered_image_door_4)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.01)

                screen.blit(image_door_5, centered_image_door_5)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.01)

                screen.blit(image_door_6, centered_image_door_6)
                pygame.display.update()
                        
                var_door = 1
                    
            else:
                screen.blit(image_door_6, centered_image_door_6)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.01)
                    
                screen.blit(image_door_5, centered_image_door_5)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.01)

                screen.blit(image_door_4, centered_image_door_4)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.01)

                screen.blit(image_door_3, centered_image_door_3)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.01)

                screen.blit(image_door_2, centered_image_door_2)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.01)

                screen.blit(image_door_1, centered_image_door_1)
                pygame.display.update()
                        
                var_door = 0
```

I do not understand why it does not work. I tried rearranging the order that the while loop checks but even that doesn't work. My guess is for some reason it never checks if the escape key is pressed and its getting stuck on the door function, but the door function doesn't have any loops in it.

Comment: Why does your `door()` function, *also* have an event loop ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You call `pygame.event.get()` inside `door()`. That will remove all events from the queue: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get

Comment: sorry I do not quite understand what you mean. I do call pygame.event.get() inside door()

Comment: Yes, don't do that. Only have one place in the code where the events are consumed.

Comment: I removed it and now my door animation is screwed up. Now I can press and hold the button and the door opens and closes really quickly. I do not want this. I want it that when you click the button once, it opens the door, and when it is clicked again, it closes.

Comment: You should have specified that in your question. Use another boolean variable to track the open/closed state of the door.

Comment: i do, that is the purpose of the var_door variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying the even loop twice which is why you loose some events. Change your main loop to this:

```py
while True:
    mouse_down = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print("key pressed")
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                print("key pressed")
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_down = True

    door(mouse_down)
```

and change `def door()` to `def door(mouse_down)`, then remove the second event loop from the `door()` function

Comment: this didn't work, error said door takes 0 positional arguments but one was given

Comment: Yes, you have to add the parameter to the definition of `door()`,  I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

As you are calling `pygame.event.get()` inside `door()`, the event queue will be empty in the main loop.

A possible solution is to store the list returned from `pygame.event.get()` and use it in both loops.

Comment: So i removed the pygame.event.get() in my door function and now my door animation doesn't work. It just opens then closes really quickly. If I spam the button that opens/closes it I can get it to change state. But what i want is that when the button is clicked, the door opens, and when it is clicked again, it closes.

Comment: What I am wondering is how do i do what you suggested, and will that fix my (new) problem?

Comment: That should not be happening. Can you edit with the new code pls?

Comment: it got fixed so don't worry. Thank you for trying tho :D

Answer (score -2):

Place the door() function cose to the left side aligning below the while .
As python works the door() is under while loop. Inform me if it works or please add detail about why is the door() in while loop and the use of door().

Comment: sorry I do not quite understand what you want me to do